# Breadth-First Traversal with a Tree that is implemented with vectors

Tags: c++, tree, breadth-first-search

```
    class Employee {
    public:
        const std::string const getName();
        const std::vector<Employee>& const getSubordinates();
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Employee> subordinates;
    };

    void printEmployeeLevels(Employee e)
    {
    }
```

My program is supposed to be able to use breadth-first traversal to print out the names of employees in an hierarchy. For example, a given Employee e could have subordinates a and b. Employee a may have subordinates c and d, and employee b might have subordinate f. Then subordinate c may have subordinate g.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to apply this to a binary tree that doesn't really have a node structure with the attributes of left and right child. My main question that I have is that: If I use a queue to do this traversal, should I make it a queue of Employee objects, or a queue of vector of Employee objects?

```
    void printEmployeeLevels(Employee e)
    {
        Queue<Employee> q;

        q.enqueue(e);

        while (1){
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            Employee k = q.front();
            std::vector<Employee> v = k.getSubordinates();
            for (int i = 0; i < k.getSubordinates().size(); ++i)
            {
                q.enqueue(v[i]);
                std::cout << v[i].getName() << " ";
            }
            q.dequeue();
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        }
    }
```

The expected output is:  (given the scenario above where the order of the children nodes don't matter)

e
a b
c d f
g

Comment: If an employee can have more than 2 children, a Binary Tree isn't suitable for representing this data structure. So you may need to step back and rethink your design.

Comment: A `queue` of `Employee` objects. You are searching a tree of `Employee`s, not a tree of `vector`s of `Employee`s. And like @Xirema said, it should just be a tree, not necessarily a binary tree.

Comment: @MikeBorkland Okay, that makes more sense, thank you. I accidentally made the mistake of terming it a binary tree, and not just a tree.